# как работает функция EncryptFileA C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

В целом, мне понятно то, что она делает из названия, но к примеру, если мне надо узнать ключ которым был зашифрован файл или как вообще происходит шифрование.
Мне нужно сделать ПО которое шифрует флешку, но если я зашифрую файлы на ней таким образом, то расшифровать смогу только на своем компе, так как функция не требует ничего кроме пути до файла, следовательно никакого пароля я не имею. Есть ли похожие функции но с ключом?

Comment: Смотрите в сторону bitlocker https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secprov/win32-encryptablevolume